# Caching data and images in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I searched on google for how to do data(xml) and image caching on windows phone 7, but did not find any luck. Please direct me to the right place from where I can read about caching mechanism in wp7. (FYI : I use HttpWebRequest to make request to the server and receive response as xml).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI commenting does not bump your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the Isolated Storage to cache both your data & images.

Essentially, you could write key-value pairs or entire files (using byte stream) into the sand-boxed Isolated Storage.

See if the two links below help:

- [31 Days of Windows Phone | Day #15: Isolated Storage](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/15/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-15-isolated-storage/)
- [Silverlight 2 - Saving and Retrieving Images from IsolatedStorage](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=234&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check the [WP7Contrib](http://wp7contrib.codeplex.com/) - it provides pattern and implementations for caching transient data on WP7. It might give you some ideas on how you can achieve what you want.

I am a contributor to this OSS project and this is not a case of self publication honest :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I found this great class which others might find useful to know about:
[Kawagoe Toolkit - PersistentImageCache](http://kawagoe.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Storage.PersistentImageCache&referringTitle=Storage.ImageCache)

Answer (score 1):

There is also a really great auto request and caching framework that came out not too long ago. It's called AgFx and it's available on Codeplex and Nuget I believe. I'm on my phone now or else I'd provide links.

Anyway, I've heard AgFx rocks, but personally, I haven't worked with enough to offer comments. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For caching images you can use [JetImageLoader](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/jet-image-loader), I created it for application, where we need to load, cache and show big amount of logos, icons and so on.

It can be used as binding converter, so *you should not even change your code! Just update your XAMLs!*

Please, check out [samples in repository](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/jet-image-loader), you'll love it ;)

**Features:**

- Caching on disk
- Caching in memory
- Fully asynchronous
- Available as binding converter or programmatically from your code
- Fully open source, fork and improve it!

Here is the example:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl, Converter={StaticResource MyAppJetImageLoaderConverter}}"/>
```

P.S. I am sorry, that I copying my answer from another questions, but image caching on windows phone is huge problem and I want to share my solution, so everybody can use it and improve for developers community